# Unable to compile TypeScript - No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am using using typescript with NodeJS and express.

```
    this.app.listen(port, (err: any) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err", err)
      } else {
        console.log(`Server is listing on port ${port}`);
      }
    });
```

They above code gives me error in visual studio code and also when i try to compile typescript. I am getting the following error message when i try to compile the typescript.

> No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
>
> Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2769)
>
> index.d.ts(1205, 5): The last overload is declared here.
> Blockquote

I have tried the below code: I still get the same error.

```
this.app.listen(port, (err: any, req: express.Request, res: express.Response)
```

I could not seem to understand why I am getting this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the type of `this.app`? It seems like it does not take any argument while your callback does.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. ````public app: express.Application;```` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are five overloads available for `listen` method. And, none of them take  callback as `(error) => void`. See here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/ts4.0/index.d.ts#L1110-L1115

[Permalink, if the above link does not work](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5250d9f57abae606f5cd324485029860038f69db/types/express-serve-static-core/ts4.0/index.d.ts#L1110-L1115)

```
    listen(port: number, hostname: string, backlog: number, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
    listen(port: number, hostname: string, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
    listen(port: number, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
    listen(callback?: () => void): http.Server;
    listen(path: string, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
    listen(handle: any, listeningListener?: () => void): http.Server;
```

So, you will have to do the following:

```
 this.app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listing on port ${port}`);
});
```

Or may be

```
 const server = this.app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listing on port ${port}`);
  });
 server.on('error', e => console.error("Error", e));
```